# JQuery inconsistency?

Tags: jquery

I realized that given the following:

```
foo = {a:'aa', b:'bb'} 

$.each(foo, function(k,v) { ... 
$(foo).each(function(k,v) { ...
```

the values of k,v is different in both cases. Is it me that is weird or is jquery inconsistent?

**EDIT**

If you come here to explain the difference between $.each and $(foo).each, I want to clarify that I know the difference between the two.

Comment: `$( foo ).each( ...` doesn't work if `foo` is a plain object. It won't iterate its properties... When you need to iterate the properties of an object, I recommend `Object.keys( foo ).forEach( ...`.

Comment: What do you mean by plain object? I am treating foo as a dictionary/hashmap/hash

Comment: A plain object is an object created from an object literal (like `foo` in your example above). Objects created from object literals are usually called just objects. However, since functions and arrays are also objects, we say "plain object" to stress that it's not one of those, but a simple object. (Functions, arrays, host objects, etc. are object that have additional special functionality. Plain objects are the only kind of objects that *don't* have any special behavior.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Under the `"Working with plain objects"` section of the [`jQuery()`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1) docs, there are a number of options, but enumerating with `.each()` isn't one of them.

> **Working With Plain Objects**
>
> At present, the only operations supported on plain JavaScript objects wrapped in jQuery are: `.data()`, `.prop()`, `.bind()`, `.unbind()`, `.trigger()` and `.triggerHandler()`. The use of `.data()` (or any method requiring `.data()`) on a plain object will result in a new property on the object called `jQuery{randomNumber}` (eg. jQuery123456789).

You should use the generic `$.each()` enumerator.

Comment: yeah I think assuming that every function can be applied both ways is a big mistake

Comment: @disappearedng: Until you asked, I didn't know you could pass an object as the first arg. IMO, the jQuery function is far too overloaded with different behavior.

Answer (score 0):

foo alone is an object literal, $(foo) is a jQuery object.

Answer (score 0):

Its because you are "selecting" the object (i.e. DOM stuff) with the second method, not iterating the object.

Comment: @disappearedng - do i detect some sarcasm?

Answer (score 0):

In your first example you are iterating over an Object which equates to:

```
$.each( foo, function( key, value ) {...
```

and your second example, you are iterating over a selection of DOM nodes which equates to

```
 $(foo).each( function( index, element ) {...
```

I hope that clears things up